# Why isn't my Google +1 button code working?

Tags: javascript, google-plus-one

I can't figure out why my code for the Google +1 button isn't working as I expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/EF8eE/

When you press the +1 button, an `alert` should pop up.

Here I got a callback function:

```
function cb(obj) {
    alert();              //alert
    console.log(obj);     //Then show obj in console
}​
```

But never the callback never gets fired. I followed every single step according to the [spec](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/), and the funniest thing is that I got it working before... But now it just does not work at all. Strange!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plusonetag) (emphasis added),

> you can use this HTML5-valid +1 tag (the class attribute must be set to `g-plusone`, and **any button attributes must be prefixed with `data-`**).

So change

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" callback="cb"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-callback="cb"></div>
```

*Ta-da!* http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/FtETf ♫

Comment: It is funny that my code is generated by the [generator from Google](http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html), and it is wrong.

Comment: @Derek wow, you're right! You should **absolutely** file a bug report.